# What is this item from the wiki homepage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[The Minecraft wiki homepage](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki) associates some of its internal navigation links with  icons of in-game items. Most of them are regular items like a compass or pickax, but the "Missing pages" sprite is something I don't recognize:

[image: A maroon octagon gem-looking thing]

Cropped: [image]

It doesn't look like [any of the real items in the game](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item). What is it? What's the story behind it? What makes it associated with the idea of "Missing pages"?

I tried to isolate the image file to see if its filename would shed any light on the matter, but [it turned out to just be part of a spritesheet](https://minecraft.wiki/w/media/minecraft.gamepedia.com/0/07/FrontPageSprite.png).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That is a ruby. The ruby was originally intended to be used instead of the emerald during the 1.3 update but was decided against in favor of the emerald due to similarities in color with redstone.

It's association with missing pages would be that it was cut from the game and as such, is "missing".

---

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Unused_features#Ruby)